# Write numbers from 1 to 100 using fork() and pipe()

Tags: c, pipe, fork, ipc

I need to write a program with 2 processes, where one writes even numbers and another writes uneven numbers. In the result, I must have numbers in order from 1 to 100.

I type this code, but when it came to processes part, it got stuck in the `printProc()` function. I guess the problem is in reading and writing in the pipe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int fd[2];

int printProc(int startNumber, int procNumber);

int main()
{
    pid_t childpid;

    pipe(fd);
    int start = 0;
    write(fd[0], &start, sizeof(start));

    if ((childpid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
    }

    if (childpid == 0)
    {
        printf("run child\n");

        printProc(1, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("run parent\n");

        printProc(2, 1);
    }

    return 0;
}

int printProc(int startNumber, int procNumber)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("output.txt", "a+");

    int num = startNumber;
    int proc;

    while (num <= 100)
    {
        read(fd[1], &proc, sizeof(proc));

        if (proc == procNumber)
        {
            fprintf(f, "%d", num);
            num = num + 2;
            proc = (proc + 1) % 2;
            write(fd[0], &proc, sizeof(proc));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why global ? why open a file ? why ignore return value ? The manual of [`pipe()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) give an exemple code that almost do what you need... did you read the manual before use a function ?

Comment: @Nicholas Goncharov  It is much better when the entire profile is written in English.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 pipes, when a process had write the number, it will write some data to one pipe so the other process will know that it can write his own number, etc.

Exemple of implementation:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
  int parent_to_child[2];
  int child_to_parent[2];
  if (pipe(parent_to_child) == -1 || pipe(child_to_parent) == -1) {
    perror("pipe");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  pid_t cpid = fork();
  if (cpid == -1) {
    perror("fork");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  if (cpid == 0) {
    close(parent_to_child[1]);
    close(child_to_parent[0]);

    int i = 1;
    bool buf;
    ssize_t ret;
    while ((ret = read(parent_to_child[0], &buf, sizeof buf)) > 0) {
      fprintf(stdout, "%d ", i);
      fflush(stdout);
      if (write(child_to_parent[1], &buf, sizeof buf) != sizeof buf) {
        break;
      }
      i += 2;
    }

    close(parent_to_child[0]);
    close(child_to_parent[1]);
  } else {
    close(parent_to_child[0]);
    close(child_to_parent[1]);

    int i = 2;
    bool buf = true;
    ssize_t ret;
    while (i <= 100 &&
           write(parent_to_child[1], &buf, sizeof buf) == sizeof buf &&
           (ret = read(child_to_parent[0], &buf, sizeof buf)) > 0) {
      fprintf(stdout, i != 100 ? "%d " : "%d\n", i);
      fflush(stdout);
      i += 2;
    }

    close(parent_to_child[1]);
    close(child_to_parent[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: @TobySpeight First a meta about stackoverflow will be more useful... I don't understand why you link a question of meta.stackexchange.com. Secondly, I decide to not explain a self explain code. There are a lot of other question about how work `pipe()` or `fork()`, this is not what OP ask, "Write numbers from 1 to 100 using fork() and pipe()", I literally answer the question, the OP as show me some work, I think that deserve some help. Downvote me or not I don't think code only answer are bad, If I really need to explain this code I will end by explain C, that will take too many time.

Comment: By the way, I don't think my solution is "perfect", it's just a possible solution. By the way, I didn't make the code produce the exact solution on purpose ;).

Comment: @Stargateur: as you don't provide any explaination on the code, it is not evident at first sight that it does not meet one OP's requirement: *2 processes, where one writes even numbers and **another** writes uneven numbers*. And no, code without a single comment is not *self explain* code.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I didn't say self documented, but self explained... Whatever, I already tired of this, you make me realize that OP describe a totally different behavior in the question and in the title, This question require IPC and I don't want to answer a question about this mess.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use a mutex here. Your critical section would consist of three operations:

- checking if it's your turn to write
- if above is true, write to output
- if you wrote to output, signal the other process that it's his turn

Here is the code that achieves that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main() {
    pthread_mutex_t *pmutex;
    short * even;
    pthread_mutexattr_t attrmutex;

    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attrmutex);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attrmutex, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

    pmutex = mmap(NULL, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    even = mmap(NULL, sizeof(short), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    pthread_mutex_init(pmutex, &attrmutex);


    pthread_mutex_lock(pmutex);

    *even = 0;

    if(fork() == 0){
        int a = 2;

        while(a <= 100) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(pmutex);
            if(*even) {
                printf("%d\n", a);
                *even = 0;
                a = a + 2;
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(pmutex);
        }

        return 0;
    }else {
        int a = 1;

        printf("%d\n", a);
        *even = 1;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(pmutex);
        a = a + 2;
        while(a <= 99) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(pmutex);
            if(!*even) {
                printf("%d\n", a);
                *even = 1;
                a = a + 2;
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(pmutex);
        }

    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(pmutex);
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attrmutex);
}
```

Both processes share two variables: `pmutex` (for synchronisation) and `even` (for checking which process is allowed to print).

Comment: look like these feature are not enable everywhere, http://rextester.com/MBCTYE81393 don't work but your code work on my machine. maybe your code will improve by adding error checking.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @Stargateur, sure this code could be improved in a lot of ways, but I wanted to share minimal example which worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use pipes to synchronize 2 processes, you really should use a pair of pipes, the former read by proc1 and written by proc2, the latter read by proc2 and written by proc1. From there you pass the read and write handles to `printProc` and that is all.

But there is another problem in your code: you open an output file in both processes in buffered mode (with `fopen`). So each process will have its own buffer. Both buffers will be fed separetely and only written to file at close time, which is not what you want: you must open the output file before the fork, and use it in non buffered mode.

So your code could become:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


int printProc(int startNumber, FILE *f, int fdin, int fdout);

int main()
{
    pid_t childpid;
    int fd[4];
    FILE *f;

    pipe(fd);
    pipe(fd + 2);
    int start = 0;
    write(fd[0], &start, sizeof(start));
    f = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    if (f == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }
    setbuf(f, NULL);             // use unbuffered mode for output.txt

    if ((childpid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
    }

    if (childpid == 0)
    {
        printf("run child\n");

        printProc(1, f, fd[1], fd[2]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("run parent\n");

        printProc(2, f, fd[3], fd[0]);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}

int printProc(int num, FILE *f, int fdin, int fdout)
{
    int proc;

    while (num <= 100)
    {
        read(fdin, &proc, sizeof(proc));

        fprintf(f, "%d\n", num);
        num = num + 2;
        write(fdout, &proc, sizeof(proc));
    }
    return 0;
}
```